# How to take arguments, accept user input and store data?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I have a list of

```
PID_short  PID_full 
   420     44101445
   419     44101375
   418     44101344
   417     44100125
   416     44095813
   415     44100240
```

```
data <- data.frame(PID_short = seq(from = 420, to = 415, by = -1),  
                   PID_full = c(44101445, 44101375, 44101344, 44100125, 44095813, 44100240))
```

I want to create a Graphic User Interface which when I key in the `PID_short`, it will show the `PID_full`.
For example when I key in `420`, it will show `44101445`.

I am really new to `R`. But I tried and here is my code :

```
  library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(title=h3("Please select the information :", align = "center")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("slide","Select the value of PID_short ", min = 415, max = 420, value = 417)      
      ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("out")
    ))))


server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$out <- renderText(
    paste("The PID_full is:",input$slide)
)})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Where should I modify my code? Or how should I write in a better way? Please help me...I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the dataframe so that you keep only the rows for which `PID_short` is equal to the input. Then you select the value of `PID_full` with `select`:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(PID_short = seq(from = 420, to = 415, by = -1),  
                   PID_full = c(44101445, 44101375, 44101344, 44100125, 44095813, 44100240))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(title=h3("Please select the information :", align = "center")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("slide","Select the value of PID_short ", min = 415, max = 420, value = 417)      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("out")
    ))))


server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$out <- renderText(
    paste("The PID_full is:", 
          data %>% 
            filter(PID_short %in% input$slide) %>% 
            select(PID_full))
  )})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: it works !! Sincerely thanks to you very much. Really really much. Wish you stay healthy and get rid off COVID-19. Once again I very appreciate it. I couldn't express my thankfulness at here but yea, thank!!!